# DataTemplate View Renders but collection data does not

Tags: c#, xaml

I am brand new to XAML, WPF and data binding so this might be a dumb question.  I have a VM, AllTransactionViewModel with a collection of PurchaseTransactions.  I have a view, via a Resource Dictionary, that renders each PurchaseTransaction in the collection in a ListView.  I can get the View to render in the main window but I the data does not populate.

View - AllTransactionsView.Xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="BudgetApp.Views.AllTransactionsView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="300" Height="97">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource
        x:Key="AllTrans"
        Source="{Binding Path=AllTransactions}"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
<ListView
    DataContext="{StaticResource AllTrans}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding}" >
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn
                Header="Name"
                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Name}"
                Width="Auto"/>
            <GridViewColumn
                Header="Transaction Type"
                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=TransactionType}" />
            <GridViewColumn
                Header="Amount"
                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Amount}"
                />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

DataTemplate in MainWindowResoures.Xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary 
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:BudgetApp.ViewModels"
xmlns:vw="clr-namespace:BudgetApp.Views">

<DataTemplate x:Key="allTransTemplate" DataType="{x:Type vm:AllTransactionViewModel}">
    <vw:AllTransactionsView/>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:TransactionViewModel}">
    <vw:TransactionView />
</DataTemplate>
```

MainWindow.XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="BudgetApp.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:BudgetApp.ViewModels"
    xmlns:vw="clr-namespace:BudgetApp.Views"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="590.717" Width="767.194">
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="MainWindowResources.xaml"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ContentControl 
        Content="{Binding AllTransactions}"
        ContentTemplate="{StaticResource allTransTemplate}">
    </ContentControl>


</Grid>
```

Finally, the AllTransactionViewModel class:

```
class AllTransactionViewModel: ViewModelBase
{
    private BudgetEntities _context;

    public AllTransactionViewModel()
    {
        _context = new BudgetEntities();
        AllTransactions = new ObservableCollection<TransactionViewModel>();
        GetAllTransactions();
    }

    public void GetAllTransactions()
    {
        foreach (var transaction in _context.PurchaseTransactions)
        {
            AllTransactions.Add(new TransactionViewModel
            (
                transaction.TransactionDate,
                transaction.TransactionType.Description,
                transaction.Name,
                transaction.Memo,
                (double)transaction.Amount,
                transaction.IsApproved,
                transaction.PurchaseType.Description
            )
            );
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<TransactionViewModel> AllTransactions { get; private set; }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, when working with `CollectionViewSource` the binding (on `ListView`) should be:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource AllTrans}}"
```

You don't need the data context in this case. If you have more code than shown, and you actually need data context then leave items source as original and instead change data context:

```
DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource AllTrans}}"
```

The reason for the "weird" binding use is that you actually need `CollectionViewSource.View` as the items source. Binding has a special treatment when the source object is CVS and it gets the view automatically. `StaticResource` doesn't have the special treatment, and you can't use `{StaticResource AllTrans.View}` since it means to get the key in property `View` of `AllTrans` type, a type that doesn't exist.

[As a side note, maybe `DataContext="{StaticResource AllTrans}" ItemsSource="{Binding View}"` will work, never tried it]

The above should fill the items, but I'm not sure what will happen with the conflict of a data template with data type `TransactionViewModel` and the fact that you use `DisplayMemberBinding` on your columns. This might mess the items, but you still should be able to see that there are some items in the list view.

Comment: This is exactly what's happening. 8 items (the amount of records in my data source) show up in the listview but no text.  I think I'm using the wrong control.  Either way, thank you. Your explanation really helps.

Comment: And the reason why no data was showing up was because I didn't have getter and setters on my object properties...